# To prove that these matrices are invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices such that $||I - AB|| < 1$. Prove that $A$ and $B$ are invertible, and $$A^{-1} = B \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (I - AB)^k \text{ and } B^{-1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (I-AB)^k A.$$

Which norm are we talking about?

Comment: Probably the supremum-norm, but in principle there are different options, for examples look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm. So the norm should be mentioned in the question (or you should be able to derive it from the space your matrices live in).

Comment: When a matrix norm is stated for questions related to limits without any illustration, the norm is generally taken to be the "operator norm". If a question is about topology, it merely means an arbitrary norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter which norm you take. It only needs to be compatible with matrix multiplication, $\|AB\|\le \|A\|\cdot \|B\|$ for all $A,B$.

The problem can be solved using Neumann's series: If $\|K\|\le 1$, then $I-K$ is invertible with
$$
(I-K)^{-1} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty K^i.
$$
Now set $K=I-AB$, and suitably multiply the identity.

Comment: thanks! this makes perfect sense.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit? Intuitively, it makes sense that the geometric series would converge to that, but how does that follow rigorously? And if you just expand that and multiply on both sides with $AB$, what's the significance of $||K|| \leq 1$. Why would it not work without that? Is it because then we could find a vector whose norm would get larger and larger as we $i$ increases, and so that the sum would not converge?

Comment: The space of $n\times n$ matrices is finite-dimensional and complete. Then one can argue that the series converges: check that the sequence of partial sums is Cauchy.